# HTML tags in database bad practice or good practice?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css, database

Sometimes I need to format specific data or part of it that comes from the database .

For example :

If i have a desc (stored in DB) like this :

---

*HTML 4 has been tweaked, stretched and augmented beyond its initial scope to bring high levels of interactivity and multimedia to Web sites. Plugins like Flash, Silverlight and Java have added media integration to the Web, but not without some cost.*

---

and i wanna to format the last line , change the font and color for example .

What 's the best practice to do this ?

embedding `HTML` tags in my database ??Is this safe and the best practice or there 's some way to separate the structure layer from the presentation layer  from the behavior layer ?

Comment: As a side note - I must say that storing it in the db is much harder to maintain.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you plan to manipulate or search upon the stored data then do not store HTML markup in your database. Imagine that at some point you're asked to change the fonts from Tahoma to Georgia, change `<b>` tags to `<strong>` or allow the users to search on the HTML column; and searches for **strong** end up returning irrelevant information because strong is also a frequently used HTML tag.

Storing HTML markup in your database is also a bad idea if you do not check what is being stored. A malicious script tag such as `<script>location = 'http://otherwebsite'</script>` is just one naive example.

Ideally you should store the data as-is or use some kind of markup such as (wiki or markdown) to store basic formatting information.

Answer (score 5):

There IS some way to separate the data from the presentation.  You keep them separate!  If you want to do some formatting on that text that you pulled from the database, go ahead and do that in your application code.  Note that structural markup is an entirely different topic from presentation markup (font, color, layout, etc)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content talks about this very point and makes a clear separation between presentation markup and structural markup in the paragraph under Intended Meaning.

Storing formatting tags in your data generally points to poor separation between the two layers or a data model that isn't sufficient to represent your data properly.  As the author is storing data in a database, that might indicate that he has just a single field for holding the "content block" of an article rather than multiple fields for the author, title, body, references, etc.  For user input data, we often fall back to a markup inside the user content for designating structure. That happens through "fake" html tags or even real html/xml tags like `<h1>`, `<em>`, `<a>`, etc.

Note that I'm not objecting to structural markup on principle but I would look carefully at why it's required if you're storing it in a database.  I am objecting to presentation markup on principle.

Comment: Should i be **punished** for not _separating_ the `data` from the `presentation` in this comment?

Comment: Cute.  Just so someone doesn't read this and get confused thinking you were actually serious...  The major difference between the author's question and this comment is that the author has the control necessary to separate the data from presentation.  It may require restructuring the data model slightly to make the type of data easier to distinguish (markup indicating structure is common as is breaking data into multiple fields based on purpose) while you do not have the ability to do so in the comment.  Though, note that `structural` markup is NOT presentation.

Comment: The OP wanted to change the color of some part of the text; IMHO this is clearly the markup.

Comment: color is purely presentation.  "part of the text" is structural.

Comment: In my first comment, i changed the font-weight of the part of the text, is this structural?

Comment: The designation of the part of the text that you wanted changed (ie, "I want the *title* to be bigger please") is a structural designation.  The thing we do with the title (making it bigger) is presentation.  In terms of html, it's the difference between `<h1>` and `<h1 style='font.....'>` or `<font>`.

Comment: "(ie, "I want the title to be bigger please")" - and in this comment you wanted the "title" word to be italicized, is this a presentation layer?

Comment: Yes.  "title" is the thing that we need to identify and "italics" is the way we want it to look.  It's very very easy to blur the two things and in some cases, we make practical decisions to do so for ease of implementation.  Heck, it's a line I've blurred accidentally plenty of times myself.  But in making a tradeoff like that, we are trading ease of implementation for ease of maintenance down the road and that is the key point behind the mantra to separate data from presentation.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_presentation_and_content for more info.

Comment: If the two things are very easy to blur, then how did you identified which of the two things is applicable there? Also, in some cases the ease of implementation doesn't interfere the ease of maintenance, while separating the things would be a huge overkill.

Comment: Practice :)  Do you have examples of "some cases" that's non-trivial?

Comment: "_Practice_" - you do know nothing of the OP setup, so i don't see how practice helps you to identify which of the two things is applicable there. "_Do you have examples of "some cases" that's non-trivial?_" - CMS with only the one user who has the right of changing the data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8159/discussion-between-gfortune-and-penartur)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on where the data comes in to DB.

If you're the only one who changes the DB content, then it is perfectly normal to store HTML tags in it.

Otherwise, if you store your users input in DB, there are two approaches:

1) To sanitize the input supplied by your users (either on store or on display) to make sure no malicious data will be displayed.

2) To use some intermediate markup language with the limited possibilities (such as BBCode), and to compile it to HTML (again, either on store or on display).

Answer (score 2):

I can not recommend to store any html tags inside your database. In the end you will find yourself lost if your codebase gets bigger and as well if you want to change your html. For example add some arguments to your html tags like classes or similar. You would need to "fix" all the html tags with sql statements. This also counts for the case you want to do something else with your data. For example create RSS Feeds or export it to another format like for example an excel sheet or similar.

Why do you want to do it anyway? I am sure tere is a better solution to your problem.
Try to separate the content form the application layer. Normelize your data and put paragraphs for example in a new dataset. If you really need to for example color one word, I would follow the suggestion that has already been posted. Use some own syntax like [color-a][/color-a]. The export problem could  however been solved by striptags()

Comment: Instead of adding [color-a][/color-a], it would be better to add [title][/title] or [footer][/footer] or [phone][/phone] or ...  In that way, you can decide what color/size/layout a footer or phone or title should have and the structural tags give additional meaning to the content.  This is, of course, assuming that it isn't better to split this content apart into separate fields in the database.

Answer (score 1):

You can use blob field, however you won't be able to do full searching on it iirc. If you have a column with the template name as a value and a blob with the html template value then this will work out just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IMO it's perfectly fine to store HTML in your database.  You sound smart enough to not allow just anything to go into the DB without validation.

You just need to be careful about how it's updated.  If you are inserting to the database via code:

INSERT INTO myTable Values(x + y + z)

if the variable x has some HTML in it with single quotes for example, no bueno.

Answer (score 1):

I think the content of the string you stored in database has nothing to do with the presentation layer, its only affection is how your business layer provide the html string (directly read from database or decorate it later) to the presentation layer.